# How to pass javascript based capability tests to server, and have server send markup based on test results

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, seo

I'm considering doing capability/feature tests with JS and sending the results back to the server so it knows what it can/cannot send to client.

It's the same idea as modernizr server -  https://github.com/jamesgpearce/modernizr-server

The problem I'm running into is communicating the JavaScript results back to the server on initial page load. I'm not sure what options are available but I know there are not a lot. I've tested setting a cookie and instantly reloading the page so PHP can read the results yet I'm concerned from an SEO standpoint. It just seems like instantly reloading a page will have some adverse affects, also I'm particularly worried if the refresh is on a page that has a form. Once the cookie is set and the user goes to another page, it works fine, it's just figuring out how to serve the content on the initial page load based on the capability tests. I've had a few different thoughts like just using JS to serve the markup on the initial page load and let PHP read the cookie on subsequent page loads, but I'm just not sure what might be the best solution.

I'm just at a loss as to what other options there are. I don't know which direction I should be looking in or if there is any direction at all. I don't know if AJAX would be able to help with this or not. I feel like I'm close, but figured maybe if I asked the community someone might have a good solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modernizr-server uses the method you described, it sets a cookie and then reloads the page.  (Actually, it doesn't do any content output, the only thing on the initial page load is the JavaScript itself. Has an exit; statement if the cookie it's looking for isn't found.)  Anyone who has JavaScript off could probably expect a blank page with it.

It looks like you have a couple of options (this is non-exclusive, there are more.):

1. Set a cookie and then reload.
2. Set a cookie, and then use AJAX to fetch the initial page's content. (As you mentioned)
3. Set an expected baseline of support (perhaps, expect no JavaScript support whatsoever), and serve that on your initial page load. If they have JavaScript on, you can either reload, or use AJAX to tell your server what things it supports and then reload chunks (or all) of the initial page.
4. Serve no-javascript content to just search engines, use option 1 or 2 for everyone else.

Option three here is the most work intensive, but probably the most inclusive option. (Edit: 3 and 4 will make sure search engines see your content)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Serving a basic version of the content makes sense for handling SEO/non-js enabled users. I guess my follow up to this question/solution is, are there any issues; SEO, caching, other?, I would need to worry about with using a JS page refresh as opposed to pulling in content with AJAX. My thoughts are with a page refresh I can keep all the code in one file, and parse out views of the code with PHP reading the cookie value, where with ajax I have to split up the views/files. I guess I'm just leery of using an instant page refresh. Something about it just seems kinda wrong.

Comment: As far as SEO goes, there's no real difference between using a full page refresh or AJAX to update content, since the search spiders will never see either. (As I'm aware)  I don't think caching would pose any issues with the refresh method.  AJAX sometimes has caching issues, but they're usually pretty easy to fix.  If I were to do it with AJAX, I would see if I could set up my view to return just the content of the largest possible chunk if called from AJAX (through GET param?) and otherwise have it output the full page complete with head tag and such.  Refresh method is certainly easier.